# Best 3D model file format to load animaton

Tags: directx-10

I am a bigginer in game programming and now I write 3D game with DirectX 10 which can be free downloaded from website. I need some animation 3D models for game personals. What is the best format for models?
Thanks.

Comment: Animation format depends on whether it's 2D or 3D. What are you creating?

Comment: This question is like "which image format is the best?". Very subjective. You'd need to expand your question with some details on what do you want to use it for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have asked this question, I'd go with **obj** file format.

Very simple, and recommended for your first model format.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003610/getting-basic-3d-models-into-an-opengl-app/2016590#2016590) for more information.

Comment: Can animation be holded in obj file?

Comment: Depends, key-frame animation can be. I often take a obj file and customise it to my liking. It depends on what your modeller outputs.

Comment: Keyframe animation summary http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_frame. As for a code example, my other answer details how to read in a model. For animation, you'd need to read in several, and use linear interpolation to transform the meshes between each key frame. If you need complex animation, you might wanna try Googling for a library or example to get you started. Not necessarily using the obj file format. I use .fx models mainly, but that is with XNA.